# Equality of dictionaries

Tags: python

I have a list of lookup fields:

```
>>> l = ['A', 'C', 'Z', 'M']
```

I would need to test the equality of 2 dictionaries on this lookup list:

```
>>> d1 = {'A': 3,'F': 4,'Z': 1}
>>> d2 = {'B': 0,'A': 3,'C': 7}
```

The equality test for any field 'x' in the list succeeds if any of the following conditions are satisfied:
1.if 'x' is not present in either of the dicts
2.if 'x' is present and d1[x]==d2[x]

The equality function would return a match ONLY IF all fields in the list succeed based on the conditions above.

So,for the above dicts -  Z fails,C fails,A succeeds,M succeeds.
However,the equality test for the dicts should report a failure.

What would be the shortest way to achieve this?

Comment: I edited my answer, see if thats what you are looking for

Comment: I was looking for a short-circuit on the first failure with something like any and comprehension

Comment: @AliBZ: Nope, Uri's answer is the answer he is looking for. Ashwin's answer is bad because it performs a linear search to search for the existence of a key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably the shortest and most elegant:

```
all( d1.get(x) == d2.get(x) for x in l )
```

Note that if x is not in both dictionary, we are comparing None with None.

EDIT:
- Following comments, using generator (not list comprehension).
- Ashwini comment is correct. Will not work if one of the dictionaries has 'None' as a value

EDIT2 (following comment):
In None can appear in dictionary, you need to have a different 'No Value'. If -9999 wouldn't work, then just generate one:

```
sentinel = object()     #a new object, guaranteed not in dictionary
all( d1.get(x, sentinel) == d2.get(x, sentinel) for x in l )
```

Comment: Works fine, but can fail if `'Z' = None` in `d1`.

Comment: Nice answer but no need for the square brackets: you can pass the generator expression `d1.get(x) == d2.get(x) for x in l` straight to `all` instead of using a list comprehension.

Comment: Remove the brackets and turn the list comprehension into a generator expression to make it perfect: `all(d1.get(x) == d2.get(x) for x in l)`.

Comment: You can work around the issue with `None` by using a unique sentinel object as the default in the `get` calls: `_sentinel = object(); all(d1.get(x, _sentinel) == d2.get(x, _sentinel for x in l)`

Comment: So ,this is the best way to search for a case where i want to make sure all elements in a list are present as keys in a dictionary - all(d1.get(x) for x in l)?The values would not be None so that's one less a worry

Comment: @IUnknown: Don't use `get` even though you know the values won't be `None`. Try something like `all(x in d1 for x in L)`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
success = True
for x in l:
  if not (((x not in d1) and (x not in d2)) or (d1.get(x) == d2.get(x))):
    success = False
```

Comment: indentation matters in Python.

Comment: @AliBZ Unfortunately you can't hit tab.  You have to use spaces.  I added two space indentation.

Comment: seems to be broken. If x in not in d1 (but in d2), d1[x] will except

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`all`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> l = ['A', 'C', 'Z', 'M']
>>> d1 = {'A': 3,'F': 4,'Z': 1}
>>> d2 = {'B': 0,'A': 3,'C': 7}

>>> all( x not in chain(d1,d2) or ((x in d1 and x in d2) and \
                                            d1.get(x) == d2.get(x))  for x in l)
False
>>> l = ['Z']
>>> d1 = {'A': 3,'F': 4,'Z': None}

>>> all( x not in chain(d1,d2) or ((x in d1 and x in d2) and  \
                                            d1.get(x) == d2.get(x))  for x in l)
False
```

`all` will return `True` only if all the values of the iterable are `True` othwerwise it'll return False.

Comment: Don't see the need for a downvote here. Point out the issue and let him fix it

Comment: :D your answer is much shorter than mine

Comment: @1_CR you should downvote in case the author didn't correct the answer. you remove the downvote or even change it to upvote (in this case!!) when it's fixed

Comment: @AliBZ, let's agree to differ on when to downvote but with you on the upvote, +1 :-)

Comment: Since I am not much familiar with 'all' - please help me translating this logic in plain english.This will help me make sure it covers all my used-cases(especially the false negative ones)

Comment: @Ashwini: No need for 1st condition. See my answer.

Comment: @downvoter Please explain the downvote, Is my solution wrong?